# In what situations were rebel vanguards used?

Tags: star-wars

Rebel vanguards were soldiers of the rebel alliance armed with missile launchers, first introduced in *A New Hope*. What function did they serve in specific combat situations? And when were they used?

Comment: where were they in ANH? I don't recall any missile launcher toting rebels...

Comment: A quick bit of checking shows that http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_vanguard_division claims that these first appeared there with no indication of when in the movie. I assume in the background of the Yavin base somewhere if this is actually true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They attacked Imperial vehicles

A glance at [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_vanguard_division) suggests that these Rebel soldiers primarily appear (or at least are described) in *Star Wars* games (video and roleplaying). As such, all such information is, of course, Legends at best.  The main discussion of their purpose comes from [*Star Wars Battlefront II: Prima Official Game Guide*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront_II:_Prima_Official_Game_Guide).

The Rebel vanguard targets Imperial vehicles with powerful weapons:

> Those looking to leave their mark on an Imperial walker can surely
> find a way in the Rebel vanguard division. When asked why someone
> would want to do this line of work, the vanguard’s most common answer
> is: “So I can blow Imperials up!” Always given the tough assignments,
> vanguards are called upon to punch holes in an Imperial vehicle
> brigade. The heavy weapons they carry provide the means to take down
> menacing enemy air and ground vehicles attempting to lay siege.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars Battlefront II: Prima Official Game Guide*</sub>

To this end, vanguards have weapons such as rocket launchers and mines:

[image]

Such heavy weapons would be overkill against individual soldiers, but very effective against vehicles.

Interestingly, they may not be a vanguard in terms of their physical position, since rocket launchers may better be fired from range. They might be more a vanguard in the temporal sense, since destroying the Empire’s vehicular strength might be worth doing before sending in ground forces.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, very effective against vehicles and large groups of soldiers. They appear a bit in Star Wars the Force Unleashed when Starkiller is trying to take back the ship station from Master Kota. Course, Those guys were Kota's own personal militia, but they became the basis for the rebel soldiers. The database in game has a bit more info on them